# Unordered list with words instead of bullet?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to modify the style of an unordered list so that instead of bullets one can have actual words in a way that would be simpler than specifying that word within the styling of the `<ul>` tag with a `:before` selector?

Comment: You are not showing what you have now that produces the “no” version, but from the image it seems that the issue is really how to get specific indentation. Yet you have accepted an answer that produces the “no” version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve what you're trying to do with the `:before` psuedo-selector without actually needing to define separate `content` for each `:before`using the **[CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)**.

Here's a demo:

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  counter-reset: my-badass-counter;
}
ul li:before {
  content: 'S'counter(my-badass-counter)'.';
  counter-increment: my-badass-counter;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One. One.</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When an item is long, this produces the “no” version, not the “yes” version.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've updated my answer which meets that requirement, please check now. No need for the downvote anymore.